# Is HMAC hash over HTTPS enough for my REST API?

Tags: rest, authentication, https, hmac

I am creating a REST API and am new to authentication.  After researching, is the following scheme safe?

The user includes a hmac hash of their request along with their secret key.  Then the server takes the request, hashes it with the key, and compares it the user provided hash.  If it checks out, complete their request.  To protect against replays, you can have them include a UTC timestamp with their request and hash.

I understand the above is pretty much two-legged oauth.

Comment: Can you define what you mean when you say "safe"?  I believe if you implement HMAC effectively within your code it a request from a client application can be trusted.  You really have to trust your client applications though as they hold the key which can allow someone else in should they allow the secret to be exposed.

Comment: Safe as in someone else can't just catch the request and repeat it.  Even if the user hashes their request with their secret, can't someone else catch the packet and resend the request with the same hash?

Comment: You are talking about replay attacks. Yes ur design can guard against these too. As your signature includes a timestamp for the generation of the hash, you can simply store an in memory cache of the signatures for each request. This cache can be set to expire in the same amount of time you use for your request window. For example you can say that requests timestamped within 15 minutes of your server time are allowed. This effectively denies any replay ability.

Comment: Does that make sense? I can draft an example of all of this for u and post as an answer in the morning.

Comment: Yes, replay attack is what I meant.  It makes sense but wouldn't a replay attack be done within a few seconds of the original request?  ie, hacker has a sniffer, as soon as it picks up a certain packet, it resends the request?

Comment: Yep, you are correct, but as you use a combination of timestamp and various other elements related to the request; every signature that you receive is pretty much guaranteed to be unique.  Therefore when you receive a request you can add the signature of the request to your cache, then you can check each incoming request to see if it's signature is already in your cache.  If so, you deny the request as being a replay.  You'll want to keep your window as small as possible to avoid unnecessary memory usage.  Make sure each cache item gets an expiry value which matches your timestamp window.

Comment: Of course, you have to check the cache first before adding anything to it.  :)